# Prove that $||A||\leq\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2}\leq\sqrt{n}\,||A||$. I cannot prove the second inequality.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, inequality, normed-spaces

I am reading "Multivariable Mathematics" by Theodore Shifrin.

The following exercise is in this book (Exercise 5.1.5 on p.201):

> Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. Prove that $||A||\leq\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2}\leq\sqrt{n}\,||A||$.

In this book, the definition of $||A||$ is as follows:

> $||A||:=\max_{||\mathbf{x}||=1} ||A\mathbf{x}||$.

I proved the first inequality but I cannot prove the second inequality.
My partial solution is here:

Let $||\mathbf{x}||=1$.
$$||A\mathbf{x}||=\sqrt{(a_{11}x_1+\dots+a_{1n}x_n)^2+\dots +(a_{m1}x_1+\dots+a_{mn}x_n)^2}.$$
By the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, $$(a_{i1}x_1+\dots+a_{in}x_n)^2\leq(a_{i1}^2+\dots+a_{in}^2)\cdot(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)$$ for any $i$ such that $1\leq i \leq m$.
So, $$||A\mathbf{x}||=\sqrt{(a_{11}x_1+\dots+a_{1n}x_n)^2+\dots +(a_{m1}x_1+\dots+a_{mn}x_n)^2}\leq\sqrt{(a_{11}^2+\dots+a_{1n}^2+\dots+a_{m1}^2+\dots+a_{mn}^2)\cdot(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)}=\sqrt{a_{11}^2+\dots+a_{1n}^2+\dots+a_{m1}^2+\dots+a_{mn}^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2}.$$
$$||A||\geq \left\lVert A\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \\
\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left\lVert A\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
\vdots \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left\lVert \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}+\dots+a_{1n} \\
\vdots \\
a_{m1}+\dots+a_{mn} \\
\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{(a_{11}^2+\dots+a_{1n}^2+\dots+a_{m1}^2+\dots+a_{mn}^2)+2(a_{11}a_{12}+\dots+a_{1{n-1}}a_{1n})+\dots+2(a_{m1}a_{m2}+\dots+a_{m{n-1}}a_{mn})}.$$
But we cannot say $$2(a_{11}a_{12}+\dots+a_{1{n-1}}a_{1n})+\dots+2(a_{m1}a_{m2}+\dots+a_{m{n-1}}a_{mn})\geq 0.$$

Comment: Hint: For $ x = ( 1/\sqrt{n} , \ldots)$, what does that imply about $||A||$?

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you very much for your hint. $\mathbf{x}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \dots,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$?

Comment: Or $\mathbf{x}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},x_2, \dots,x_n)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x=e_i$. Get $|A|^2\geq|Ax_i|^2$. Now sum over $i$.

Comment: $||A||^2\geq ||A\mathbf{e}_{i}||^2=a_{1i}^2+\dots+a_{mi}^2$. $n||A||^2\geq\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2$. $\sqrt{n}||A||\geq\sqrt{\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2}$. Max, Thank you very much for your answer!